# Recommendation system for news articles

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I am trying to create an recommendation system for similar articles. I do have a list of articles as reference and I want other new articles that I acquire from a certain API needs to be similar to those reference articles.

One way I could is just merge all of those reference article into one big article and run cosine similarity and get list of articles that are similar to to merged reference articles. Is there any other way I could implement cosine similarity?

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into `vecsim`, https://pypi.org/project/vecsim/

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into an NLP technique called Topic Modelling?
This following notebook from priya-dwivedi uses LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation):

https://github.com/priya-dwivedi/Deep-Learning/blob/master/topic_modeling/LDA_Newsgroup.ipynb